# Does Zig call defer after block breaks?

Tags: zig

Given the following snippet, does the call to unlock occur after the break or before?

```
var input_data: InputState = blk: {
    user.input_mutex.lock();
    defer user.input_mutex.unlock();
    break :blk user.input;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#defer) says:

> defer will execute an expression at the end of the current scope.

It's not worded very clearly, but it means that the `defer` statements are executed after all of the code in the current block has been executed. This includes `break` statements.

For example, an `errdefer` statement cannot be executed before the last line, because `errdefer` statements are only enabled after `return error.SomeError`, which would be the last line in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least as of zig version `0.12.0-dev.167+dd6a9caea`

Running the following snippet:

```
const std = @import("std");

fn getRandom() !u64 {
    var seed: u64 = undefined;
    try std.os.getrandom(std.mem.asBytes(&seed));
    std.debug.print("test seed: {}\n", .{seed});
    return seed;
}

pub fn main() !void {
    var value = blk: {
        defer std.debug.print("defer test seed\n", .{});
        break :blk try getRandom();
    };
    _ = value;
}
```

Will show the following in console output:

```
test seed: 6866361107008308078
defer test seed
```